# Smooth Morse function from Forman's discrete Morse function

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, morse-theory, computational-topology, discrete-morse-theory

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $K$ a triangulation of $M$, so $K$ is a regular CW-complex and in particular a simplicial complex. Assume that $M$ is compact so $K$ is finite. Let $f\colon K \to \mathbb{R}$ be a discrete Morse function (in the sense of Forman). Is is possible to define a smooth Morse function $f'\colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ with the same critical points as $f$ (and satisfying a correspondence between the indexes of the critical points)? Is it possible to do it in "an algorithmic way" (I mean that the proof is constructive)?

As far as I know, the converse was addressed by Gallais and Benedetti, am I right?

I apologize in advance if the questions are to vague or the answers are well-known. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Doesn't $f$ have critical *simplices* (not just points of $M$)? Because then I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Chris A critical k-dimensional simplex should correspond to (part of) the stable manifold of an index k critical point by analogy to handlebody decompositions.

Comment: @MikeMiller That is exactly what it is  shown in the reference I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can do the next best think. To a  Forman-Morse function $f$ one can associate  a flow on the manifold whose stationary points are precisely  the barycenters  of the faces  of your simplicial decomposition.    The Conley index of the barycenter of a critical face has the homotopy type of a sphere of the dimension of that face. The Conley index of the barycenter of a non-critical face is homotopically trivial.

Additionally, one can construct a continuous function $\tilde{f}$ on the manifold that decreases along the trajectories of this flow and whose value at a barycenter is equal to the value of $f$ on the corresponding face. As  Mike Miller correctly pointed out,  a critical face is filled out by the  trajectories exiting the barycenter.

For details  see Chapter 11 of [this paper](https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/tameflow.pdf).  The faces of the barycentric subdivision of your simplicial complex are invariant  sets of this flow, and on  such a face the flow is depicted in Figure 2, p.16 of the above paper.

It took me a while to realize that in Morse theory  the gradient flow associated to a Morse function is more important than the function itself.  The function plays a sort of accounting role and  the Morse condition  restricts the nature of the stationary points of the gradient flows.

**Remark**  A while ago I asked [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86193/combinatorial-morse-functions-and-random-permutations) on MathOverflow that is related to the abundance of discrete Morse functions. They are extremely rare as opposed to the  usual smooth Morse functions that are generic.

Comment: Do you know that this is impossible for smooth Morse functions, let's say for the trivial discrete Morse function $\mu(\sigma) = \dim \sigma$? That is, is there some smooth triangulation of a smooth manifold $M$ so that there is **not** a smooth function $f$ on $M$ so that the barycenters of the simplices are the critical points of $f$, and the unstable manifold at a critical point is the interior of the corresponding simplex? This may be a naive question, I don't know.

Comment: @MikeMiller Given a triagulation the function that associates to each face its dimension is a discrete Morse function. However,  if you randomly  assign numbers to faces, then the probability  that you get a discrete Morse function is small exponentially so as the number of faces  increases.